# Toggle pseudo class :after on specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, html

How can I enable or disable (or toggle) the 'after' pseudo class?

I'm trying to come up with something along the lines of:

```
$('.card').click(function(){

    if(pick1) {
        pick2 = $(this).css('background-color');
        id2 = $(this).attr('id');
        >>> add display:none to .card:after for the clicked div <<<

        if(pick1 == pick2 && id1!=id2) alert('Correct');
            else {
                alert('Incorrect');
                >>> remove display:none from .card:after on clicked divs <<<
            }

        pick1 = false;
        pick2 = false;
    } else {
        pick1 = $(this).css('background-color');
        id1 = $(this).attr('id');
        >>> add display:none to .card:after for the clicked div <<<  
    }
});
```

My project is here: http://jsfiddle.net/94jerdaw/29TCZ/3/

Comment: were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: yeah, thanks :) I made a separate class and added/removed it where needed.

Comment: great.  If my answer was helpful, feel free to accept it then so others know this has been resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you have add an extra class to the rule?  Like this

```
.hidden.card:after{
  display:none
}
```

Then the code can just be `$().addClass("hidden")` or `$().removeClass("hidden")`

```
if(pick1) {
    pick2 = $(this).css('background-color');
    id2 = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).addClass("hidden");

    if(pick1 == pick2 && id1!=id2) alert('Correct');
        else {
            alert('Incorrect');
            $(this).removeClass("hidden");
        }

    pick1 = false;
    pick2 = false;
} else {
    pick1 = $(this).css('background-color');
    id1 = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).addClass("hidden"); 
}
```

Comment: This. because as far as I'm aware, you can't access psuedo selectors natively with sizzle.